# Can nonce be used to achieve Idempotency in REST API?

Tags: rest

Stripe API uses a key called `Idempotency-Key` for achieving idempotency: https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests. Is this similar to a nonce?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Idempotence key on the surface level looks very similar to nonce, but they don't overlap.

A nonce should only be used once, even on a retry, you should generate new nonces.

On the other hand, an idempotence key must be reused when retrying a REST request where you don't want the side effect of the update to be applied multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

> Stripe API uses a key called `Idempotency-Key` for achieving idempotency ...

Doesn't [*idempotency*](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html) inherently mean that the client application doesn't need to know or care about the actions taken at all?
From this POV it looks a bit useless to explicitely request such for my taste.

Comment: It looks like the point of this is so you can make idempotent `POST` requests: "Sending idempotency keys in `GET` and `DELETE` requests has no effect and should be avoided, as these requests are idempotent by definition."  It doesn't mention `PUT` though, which should also be idempotent by definition.